# How to get date from previous sunday using new Date()

Tags: javascript

whats the best way to get previous sunday using new Date()?

any ideas? sorry newbie here*

Comment: What have you tried? I'd recommended looking into tutorials on how the Date object works

Comment: so, what i'm doing is. first get todays day, then i need to know what was the previous sunday date, after doing that i will add 7. so i can get a range of 7 days sun to sat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not a trivial task, here's the algorithm I suggest for you:

- Create a Date object
- Get the current day of week from the object
- If it's zero (Sunday) set it to seven
- Subtract that many days from the date*
- Done!

*This works really well thanks to some rather clever implementation. If you subtract 4 days from February 2nd, the result is January 29th.

Now it's up to you to write some code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many tutorials on the web will show you how to use Date.getDay() that returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6).
Then substract one day to your date until you get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my variant:

```
var dateNow = new Date();
var dateToday = new Date(dateNow.getFullYear(), dateNow.getMonth(), dateNow.getDate());
var dateSunday = new Date(dateToday.getTime()-dateToday.getDay()*24*3600*1000);
```

in `dateSunday` you'll get date object on sunday start.

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourDate = new Date(Date.now() - ((new Date().getDay() + 7) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

- **Date.now()** gets the current date down to the millisecond, which makes it easy to perform mathematical calculations.
- **new Date().getDay() + 7**, like one of the previous posters suggested finds the current day (0-based) and add 7 to that in order to subtract however many days we are from the most recent sunday, minus one week.
- **24 * 60 * 60 * 1000** ensures that we are subtracting that many **full days** (in milliseconds) away from our current day in order to find last Sunday.

Or, you could write some algorithm too.

Best of luck friendo. :]